# Angular 9 to 14: How to initialize at null or underfined or ... my userForm variable member in its constructor? It will be initialized wisely later

Tags: angular, initialization

I'm taking a sample code from a video training for *Angular 9*, But I'm under *Angular 14*.

The next code, compiles correctly in *Angular 9*,
it is asking `userForm: FormGroup;` to be initialized in its constructor part, or variable member declaration, when under *Angular 14*,

even if it will, later, be duly initialized in a `ngForm() / initForm()` below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-user',
  templateUrl: './new-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-user.component.scss']
})
export class NewUserComponent implements OnInit {
  /** Formulaire */
  userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  /**
   * Intialiser le formulaire.
   */
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }

  /**
   * Initialiser le formGroup.
   */
  initForm(): void {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      drinkPreference: ''
    });
  }
}
```

The IDE displays:

[image]

with the error message:
*TS2564: Property 'userForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.*

I have tried:

```
this.userForm = null;
this.userForm = undefined;
```

in my constructor, without success.
What is the correct initialization?

---

I'm not willing:

`userForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});`
in member variable initialization or constructor declaration.

My `userForm` should be created only in `initForm()` method.
It should not have any existence, even empty, before.

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: Just use an `!` mark after `userForm` and google for "strict class checking", if you want to read more.